# In a single Visualforce page can we divide half pdf and half web page?

Tags: visualforce

In a single Visualforce page, can we divide half pdf and half web page?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need at least two visualforce pages. Note the below is not my code it's from an example question when I was checking if you could do this with components. I wouldn't recommend this approach however as performance seems to take a hit and there are some limitations in regards to actions etc run in the constructor etc.

Reference - [renderAs PDF in the same page](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/29225/renderas-pdf-in-the-same-page)

Apex VF page Test1:

```
<apex:page standardController="Account" >
    <apex:detail relatedList="false" title="false"/>
    <iframe src="/apex/Test2?id={!Account.Id}" height="800px" width="800px"/>
</apex:page>
```

Apex VF page Test2:

```
<apex:page standardController="Account" renderAs="pdf" >
    <apex:pageBlock>
        <apex:pageBlockSection>
            <apex:outputField value="{!Account.Name}" />
        </apex:pageBlockSection>
    </apex:pageBlock>
</apex:page>
```